How to turn off Github Auto Code Suggestion on IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.3 (Community Edition)? MacOS
Here is what Github Co-Pilot suggests me the first time:
To turn off code suggestions from me in IntelliJ IDEA, you can follow these steps:

Go to Preferences (on macOS) or Settings (on Windows/Linux).
Navigate to Editor -> General -> Auto Import.
Under the Java section, uncheck the Show suggestions as you type box.
Click Apply and then OK to save the changes.

Well there isn't a checkbox for the "show suggestions as you type box" on Auto Import page
Then github co-pilot says:

Go to Preferences (on macOS) or Settings (on Windows/Linux).
Navigate to Editor -> General -> Code Completion.
Uncheck the Autopopup code completion box.
Click Apply and then OK to save the changes.

On the Code Completion page, i uncheck everything and it is still showing code suggestions!

Sign out of GitHub or remove the copilot plug-in?

@J.Titus I actually wanted the Github Chat, but not the inline code suggestions


Go to Preferences (on macOS) or Settings (on Windows/Linux).
Languages & Frameworks -> Github Copilot
Uncheck 'Automatically show completions'.
Github code suggestions won't show anymore



Open IntelliJ IDEA and go to Help > Find Action
Search for "GitHub Copilot"
Plugins: Github Copilot.
Slide the window to Turn OFF
Restart the Intelij IDE.

You can make it ON anytime you want.

Go to your plugins and check if you got a "Full Line Code Completion" turned on. Turn it off. This worked for me.

This worked for me:
Tools -> GitHub CoPilot -> Disable Completions (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+O)
